# Open and scroll through 42 GB text file in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, text-editors, xml

I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion) and I am trying to open and scroll through a 42 GB .XML file.

I plan on using an XML parser to parse through it and delete parts, but first I need to know how the document is structured so I can know what parts to save.

How can I open this text / XML file and scroll through it so I can get a glimpse of its structure?

I tried my default text-editor, text-mate, and that couldn't open it. I tried gEdit and that shows the first 10 or so lines, but then quits after trying to load the rest.

I would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496981/simple-free-xml-viewer-and-editor-for-osx

Comment: I'm wondering if any of these suggestions worked for you - I gave up on vi after waiting a minute to load a 63 MB file, and less crashes my terminal after navigating a few pages down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [terminal pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). Open a terminal and run

```
less file.txt
```

or

```
more file.txt
```

Comment: less has more chance of dealing with these kind of files.

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions on how I can edit it? Or should I let the script do that?

Comment: @DjangoJohnson probably best to let the script do it or to use something like `sed`.

Answer (score 11):

Well, [hexfiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) is what I use, and love to use...

[image]

If it is a text file, you just go to **Views** and uncheck **Hexadecimal** option, it will show only text.

So, for example I scrolled to line: 37802466 superfast, no glitches...

Comment: well we need to modify this to show view with new lines. Then we found our notepad++ on mac.

Comment: Perfect solution and great editor

Answer (score 1):

`vi` will not read all file at once and will cache it. Give it a try. It can also syntax-hihglight it, so it's a plus over `less`.

Comment: I tried to edit your good reply so as to place "\`" around `vi` and `less`. But so minor a correction was rejected by e-boss.
I just tried `vi` on 1 Gbyte file. It's quite fast.

Comment: I have more power over my answers. :)

Comment: "It's a plus over `less`" ;).

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for opening large text files and searching for content I found was **[glogg](https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg)**

> glogg is a multi-platform GUI application that helps browse and search through long and complex log files. It is designed with programmers and system administrators in mind and can be seen as a graphical, interactive combination of grep and less.

Unfortunately the oficial website is down. But you can download the latest release on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210717193235/http://glogg.bonnefon.org/download.html)

Although the program has not received updates for a few years. It works normally on MacOs 12 Monterey

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [ricardo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1357580/704812) and found https://github.com/variar/klogg

This is made for browsing and searching huge (log) files and has excellent search options

Apart from features of glogg it has dark mode that most of us need

Comment: How is this answer better than the one you are referring  to?

Comment: @DarkDiamond The answer I was referring to is about `glogg`, which does not support dark mode and is not maintained.  The newer one I found `klogg` supports Dark mode while it can handle huge files as well, so I thought this deserves a separate answer to make is visible to anyone like me who is looking for such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @terdon already said: Terminal pagers will work regardless how big the file is.
(42 GB... Just curious how you managed to get a file that big...)

<del>TextWrangler might be able to deal with it.</del>
I just verified that TextWrangler has a maximum limit of about 380 MB per file.

If you have a PC handy (or Wine) you can try the trail version of UltraEdit.
This can 100% certain deal with such files.

Comment: It is a crawl of content from the internet. Part of the internet. I don't have a PC handy. What if I need to edit it on a mac, what do I do then?

Comment: UltraEdit is known to work on a Mac using Wine. I routinely use it to edit files larger than the RAM of the computer. TextWrangler which is a native Mac-app might be able to do it too, but I don't know that for sure. I don't have a Mac nearby to verify that.

Comment: Try `vi`. Seriously.

Comment: @SilentStorm That's what I would do :-) , but if someone needs to ask for a tool, vi(m) is probably not the right tool for him/her. Let's be honest... VI has a learning curve. Something we Unix guys sometimes tend to forget. For someone who grow up with a point and click interface VI is scary like hell.

Comment: @Tonny VIM is scary. I'm trying to avoid it. But I will use it if I must.

Comment: @Tonny, @Django Both of you are right. `vim` is both hard for a newcomer, is a bit scary and extremely deep, but IIRC there's MacVim and a GUI version of vim. Both are easier & a tiny bit more user friendly than the original behemoth. I insisted on vim because it's battle tested in these scenarios and easily accessible. You won't need to install a bunch to see a file.

Comment: @SilentStorm MacVim is pretty nice yes. http://code.google.com/p/macvim/